# Incorrect result of ConvexRegionQ

Tags: computational-geometry

Studying [that important command](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ConvexRegionQ.html?q=ConvexRegionQ) of Mathematica in 13.2 on Windows 10, I obtain for both

```
ConvexRegionQ[ImplicitRegion[x + y + z + t + s <= 1 && {x, y, z, t, s} >= 0,{x, y, z, t, s}]]
```

and

```
ConvexRegionQ[ ImplicitRegion[x + y + z + t + s <= 1 && x >= 0 & 7 y >= 0 && z >= 0 && s >= 0 && t >= 0,{x, y, z, t, s}]]
```

> `False`

The above is not correct because `ImplicitRegion[ x + y + z + t + s <= 1 && {x, y, z, t, s} >= 0, {x, y, z, t, s}]` is the intersection of 6 hyper-planes in 5 dimensions.

Is there a workaround in Mathematica?

Comment: One could blame it on syntactic irregularities because the argument of `ConvexRegionQ` is not a `Region` at all (i.e., `RegionQ` returns `False`). But unfortunately, `ConvexRegionQ[
 ImplicitRegion[
  x + y + z + t + s <= 1 && x >= 0 && y >= 0 && z >= 0 && t >= 0 && s >= 0, {x, y, z, t, s}]]` also returns `False`.

Comment: @HenrikSchumacher: Many thanks from me to you for your valuable comment. Fixed.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a workaround found by me. Making use of the definition of a convex set and quantifiers,
one obtains

```
Resolve[ForAll[u, u >= 0 && u <= 1,  Implies[x1 + y1 + z1 + t1 + s1 <= 1 && 
{x1, y1, z1, t1, s1} >= 0 && x2 + y2 + z2 + t2 + s2 <= 1 && 
{x2, y2, z2, t2, s2} >= 0,  u*(x1 + y1 + z1 + t1 + s1) + 
(1-u)*(x2 + y2 + z2 + t2 + s2) <= 1 && u*{x1, y1, z1, s1, t1} + 
(1 - u)*{x2, y2, z2, s2, t2} >=0]], Reals]
```

> `True`